# Does the parameters $d, a, b$ uniquely determine a strongly regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory

The existence is not guanranteed of a strongly regular graph, $d$-regular, every pair of adjacent vertices having $a$ common neighbors, every pair of vertices not adjacent having $b$ common neighbors. But if it does exist for a set of parameters, should the graph ,up to isomorphism, be unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. For instance, there are $15$ different [Paulus graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PaulusGraphs.html) with parameters $(25, 12, 5, 6)$. For more information on strongly regular graphs, be sure to check Andries Brouwer's [database](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html) and [lecture notes](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/math/ipm/).